# Docker - Unable to access postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, nextcloud

im trying to setup NextCloud on Postgres with Docker but im unable to access/reach the postgress container from the nextcloud setup page.
Here is my setup:

```
docker network create --driver bridge nextcloud

docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
--name postgres \
--link cloud.mydomain.com \
--net=nextcloud \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpass123 \
-e POSTGRES_USER=nextcloud \
-e POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud \
-v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
-d postgres


docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 \
--name="cloud.mydomain.com" \
-e VIRTUAL_HOST=cloud.mydomain.com \
-v nextcloud:/var/www/html \
--net=nextcloud \
nextcloud


docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name="cloud.mydomain.com-proxy" \
--net=nextcloud \
-v /srv/gitlab:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro \
-v /root/certs:/etc/nginx/certs \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
--restart always \
jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invert the link, add the `--link postgres` to  cloud.mydomain.com:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 \
--name="cloud.mydomain.com" \
--link postgres \
-e VIRTUAL_HOST=cloud.mydomain.com \
-v nextcloud:/var/www/html \
--net=nextcloud \
nextcloud
```